# Working with Neo4J REST API

Tags: java, rest, relationship, nodes, neo4j

I have several questions.

How can I query the node by its property? I see only to query by node id.

And how can I get, for example all friends and unconfirmed friends of the node? At the moment I can do that only by querying the all relationships of the node, and iterate over it by checking the property of each relationship.

My idea as the following: a node has parameter - id (userID), relationship has properties - directions - FROM_ME or TO_ME, status - CONFIRMED, UNCONFIRMED. All the queries are performed in REST API in Java.

How can I do that in the simple way like in SQL, f.e., SELECT friends WHERE friend_id = 1?

References to some tutorials with the solutions and techniques of such questions qould be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can use indexes to quickly find nodes by a property on the node. Docs for REST here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-indexes.html

For the second question, Cypher query language makes it easy to perform these types of queries. Here is an example that gets all users that are connected to a given user via a FRIEND relationship where the "status" property of the relationship is "confirmed":

```
START user=node(123)
MATCH user-[r:FRIEND]-friend
WHERE r.status="confirmed"
RETURN friend
```

You can also add constraints on the direction of the relationship and chain multiple relationships together in a path to find friends-of-friends, etc.

Here are the Cypher docs: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html

Here are the docs on making Cypher queries via the REST API: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood that "FRIEND" is the property of the relationship? Right? But what is "friend"? I have relationships only with property "FRIEND".

Comment: What is the type of the relationship? All relationships have a type and a direction and zero or more properties. The [r:TYPE] portion of the query filters out only relationships of a given type, and the "where" portion further filters based on individual properties.